# Get Mongoose to automatically create joined document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Mongoose.js Schemas that work together with the 'populate' feature: A 'user' schema and another based on their role. E.g. 'admin'. When a user is assigned a role, a corresponding document needs to be created in a different collection with a link to the _id of the document in the users collection.  (Yes, more like an SQL database than non-relational, I know)

Currently I manually create the second document in my code whenever a user with a specialized role is created or a role is added to a user. |

I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically create this corresponding record from my schema whenever a 'user' document is created or updated with a role.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing will do it automatically, but you can use the mongoose middleware to insert our update a document in another collection pre or post save.

The post hook will have the _id populated.

If you want to do it in the pre hook (to enforce some transactional integrity) you can assign the _id manually.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go check out mongoose middleware then.  

I'd also LOVE to know why my question was downvoted.  It's pretty discouraging to new users to have your post downvoted with no reason given.

Comment: Very similar questions have probably been asked. If you don't have the credentials to mark questions as duplicates, people will voice their opinion like that.